# What is the relation between pseudogap and time reversal symmetry breaking?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, time-reversal-symmetry

Some papers concerning high-$T_c$  superconductor discuss the pseudogap and time reversal symmetry breaking.

My questions are:

- What is the characteristic of order-parameter in **pseudogap**? How to understand pseudogap?
- What kinds of superconductors would lead to pseudogap? Are there any limits to produce it?
- What is the relation between pseudogap and reversal symmetry breaking?

Comment: My (poor) understanding of the subject is that none of these questions is resolved yet. The pseudo-gap phase is one of the big unknown (but well documented experimentally) of the high-$T_{c}$ superconductors. Perhaps you could start understanding a bit better your first questions by reading the book by Leggett on quantum fluids.